# How do I display a PDF file using servlets and JSP?

Tags: jsp, pdf, servlets

Can anyone tell how to display a PDF file which is stored in my database using servlets and JSP?  Are there any specific jar files to be imported?

Comment: If the client computer has Java, then you can display the PDF using a JNLP or an applet. I have written an article [A Java PDF Web Viewer - Powered By PDFOne (for Java™)](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=195&t=A_Java_PDF_Web_Viewer_-_Powered_By_PDFOne_(for_Java_trade;)) for my company. This article contains a demo that displays a PDF file on the local computer. You could change the code so that it displays a PDF generated off the DB server-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get it as `InputStream` from DB and write it to `OutputStream` of the response along a correct set of headers. Here's a snippet assuming you're using JDBC to interact with DB.

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
// ...
InputStream input = resultSet.getBinaryStream("columnname");
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
// Write input to output the usual way.
// ...
```

When mapped on an `url-pattern` of for example `/pdfservlet`, then you can just call the servlet using `<a>` link

```
<a href="pdfservlet?id=123">click here</a>
```

or by `<object>` if you want to embed it in HTML.

```
<object data="pdfservlet?id=123" type="application/pdf" width="600" height="400">
</object>
```

You don't need any additional libraries. A complete kickoff example can be found [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html).

Comment: @BalusC It is not opening the pdf file. Its just showing a blank page. I want to open the pdf file retrieved from database, What should i do?

Comment: Perhaps input hasn't been written to output, or the content in DB is actually empty.