# Better understanding of Java I/O 

Tags: java, apache-commons, java-io

In Java network inputstream why is it not recommended that this be done :

```
 PdfReader localPdfReader = new PdfReader(item.getinputStream());
```

Where item is a `FileItem` uploaded from a client.
Instead this is recommended:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(item.getInputStream(), output);
```

What is the diference between the two?
**EDIT**
I came to know that it is because inputstream here is a network stream. So once a byte is read you cannot read it anymore. So you have to copy it to memory(IOUtils) before using it. My question is while copying to memory also you have to read the stream byte by byte right? then why doesn't the inputstream get closed there?

Comment: both FileItem and IOUtils are not part of the standard library, but instead from Apache Commons IO library. I have added the appropriate tag to the question.

Comment: I am not getting your edit.Why do you think the stream will close after reading the byte?

Comment: @Santosh : Then why doesn't the first method work?

Comment: @Ashwin please check my edit to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the difference is of **Reader and Inputstream**. In your example, a PDF doc is binary data which should not be transferred character by character but byte by byte. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367539/what-is-the-difference-between-reader-and-inputstream) in the same forum for more on Reader and InputStream. Even though it mentioned wrapping of Stream by Reader, as mentioned earlier for binary data this should be discouraged.

EDIT: 1

Lets check the way Reader and InputStream's read method works

`Reader.read()` [returns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29) integer in the range 0 to 65535 (single 16-bit Unicode character)

`InputStream.read()` [returns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) byte (8-bit signed two's complement integer) of data

Now imagine if you use Reader to read binary data (which is sequence of 8 bit integer), you will end up reading two bytes (8*2) instead of one assuming it to be a character.

I have not seen the code for  `PdfReader` so not sure if it uses `java.io.Reader`. This explaination  is purly for `java.io.Reader/InputStream`. I would appreciate if you share some link or post which which says the the `PdfReader` if used in a manner you mentioned, is not good.

EDIT:2

Remember:

1. From a network, you can read the stream bytes only once.
2. If you need those bytes for multiple tasks, better store those bytes in array and used the same array multiple time

If you use

`PdfReader localPdfReader = new PdfReader(item.getinputStream());`

then PdfReader internally reads the bytes from stream and uses it to validate. It **does not** store it for any further usage.

If you use

```
IOUtils
```

It copies the bytes from network to a byte array which later can be used in `PdfReader` as well as JDBC call to store it in DB.

Comment: pls see this link. See from my first comment  of the first answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320062/how-to-store-a-pdf-file-in-postgresql-database-using-servlets -

Comment: I wish you posted this link earlier. What @BalusC has said is perfectly right. Which part you didn't understand ?

Comment: I did not understand from the 5th comment of the 1st answer. He says that from a network stream only only on  byte can be read.

Comment: Thats true. check out the javadoc of InputStream.read() method. It reads only one byte at a time.

Comment: What is the problem with that? why shouldn't this be done - PDFReader pd=new PDFReader(inputstream)? Instead why should IOUtils be used? Please explain in detail. My understanding of java i/o does not seem to be good.

Comment: In the link BalusC has said that - " Once a byte is read, it cannot be read anymore". Then how will you even copy it using the IOUtils. Because to copy also you will have to read it and then copy it.

Comment: The first time you read it, you read it using IOUtils which will copy it as well.

Comment: "The first time you read it, you read it using IOUtils which will copy it as well",when you read it you read it byte by byte right? But according to BalusC "Once a byte is read, it cannot be read anymore"

Comment: Yes. One byte you read, you store it in an array and then read next byte and store it in the same array. So on and so forth. This way you read each byte once, but store the same in byte array.

Comment: one more question does pdf reader need the bytes more than once to create a pdf file?

Comment: Nope. It needs the bytes once you pass bytes via standard constructor which takes a byte array.

Comment: Thanks got it:) you can up vote my question if you already haven't:)

Comment: @Santosh I don't know which `PDFReader` class you're referring to but the ones I found all had constructors that take `InputStreams.` So I don't know what this question is really about.

Comment: @EJP Its the widely used iText library. Check [this link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.1.0/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.java)

Comment: Exactly. So, just as I said, it has a constructor that takes an `InputStream`. So there is no need for the `ByteArrayInputStream` convolution.

Comment: @EJP Well true. But if you see the background of this question, BalusC has [mention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320062/how-to-store-a-pdf-file-in-postgresql-database-using-servlets) this "convolution", and it seems to cause some confusion to Ashwin. Check the link mentioned in the 2nd comment here and then read THIS question, that will give you idea where I am coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The streams in java use [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). It is used to add a functionality to the streams by wrapping them (decorating). My favourite is using `GZipStream` around a `FileStream`, for added compression.

Answer (score 1):

> Instead this is recommended

Recommended by whom? Why? I've never seen such a statement in any Oracle or Sun documentation since 1997. OTOH there is a lot of misinformation out there from other sources.

It might be recommended *in certain circumstances*, i.e. where you have to read the data more than once. These circumstances are very rare.

Comment: you are right. It is recommended when when you have to read the data more than once. got it:)